# Converting unicode to hex

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding, utf, chars

I have cyrillic word in my js file which charset is UTF-8 without BOM.
How can I get hex index of unicode table of my first character?
The word "Абв" and result must return hex code "0x0410".

I tried this code, but it returns wrong result:

```
var code = "А".charCodeAt(0);
var codeHex = code.toString(16).toUpperCase();
console.log(code, codeHex);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in your `console.log(code, codeHex);` you have no space between the two values `code` and `codeHex`, so you'll get to see a seemingly big value (`1040410`).

So separate like this:

```
console.log(code, ' ', codeHex);
```

and if you want a nice hex formatting, do this:

```
console.log(code, ' ', '0x' + ('0000' + codeHex).substr(-4));
```

Snippet:

```js
var code = "А".charCodeAt(0);
var codeHex = code.toString(16).toUpperCase();
document.write(code, ' ', '0x' + ('0000' + codeHex).substr(-4));
```

Comment: Well, when I typing this snippet in console it's work perfect. But when I use it from my file, it always returns: "1056  0x0420".

Comment: I changed charset of my file to ANSI and it works. But why it does not work with UTF-8?

Comment: Set the character set of your HTML file: add `<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>` and at the same time save it as UTF-8 encoding (check the character is still the same after doing that as some characters may not survive the switch).

Comment: It's ok, I checked this, it's UTF-8. But still not working with UTF-8

Comment: Anything else you are doing? I just created such a file from scratch, and it gives the correct result.

Comment: I found where is the problem.
I didn't tell you that I use iMacros plugin for Firefox, which load another script and run it dynamically. So for correctly work of another script, the iMacros have to recognize the charset UTF-8 with BOM. Anyway thank you for help, I really appreciate it. :)